# ASP.NET Core WebApi Jwt Role-based Authorization not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, jwt, asp.net-core-webapi

I have implemented a JWT Authentication/Authorization system based on a tutorial.

But Unfortunately I have no idea how to authorize the roles.

This is a role based authorizaton.

```
    public class InfoController : ControllerBase
    {
        [Authorize(Roles = "User")]
        [HttpGet("user")]
        public IActionResult UserInfo()
        {
            return Ok("User role");
        }
    }
```

When I call this `api/Info/user` I get **401** response code instead of the Status code **200** with the "User role" message. So the role-based authorization does not work.
I call it with the correct data:

```
curl -X GET "https://localhost:34545/api/Info/user" -H  "accept: application/json" -H  "Authorization: eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJ0ZXN0IiwianRpIjoiYTgwYzQ3NDQtNmYyZC00ZTAwLThhYjItMzY2MTRmYTNmMzYzIiwiaWF0IjoxNTU3NjgyMDU4LCJyb2wiOiJ3ZWItYXBpLWFjYyIsImh0dHA6Ly9zY2hlbWFzLm1pY3Jvc29mdC5jb20vd3MvMjAwOC8wNi9pZGVudGl0eS9jbGFpbXMvcm9sZSI6IlVzZXIiLCJuYmYiOjE1NTc2ODIwNTgsImV4cCI6MTU1NzY4OTI1OCwiaXNzIjoid2ViLWFwaSIsImF1ZCI6Imh0dHBzOi8vbG9jYWxob3N0OjQ0MzUwLyJ9.8uRAOsSXmKeWcYCwvN0sNFX02GNoZMaPNf6RPGkQE4E"
```

In the startup I has the following configuration:

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("api", policy => policy.RequireClaim(
               jwtClaimConfiguration[nameof(JwtClaimOptions.Rol)],
               jwtClaimConfiguration[nameof(JwtClaimOptions.ApiAccess)]
            ));
            options.AddPolicy("user", policy => policy.RequireRole(AppRole.USER));
            options.AddPolicy("admin", policy => policy.RequireRole(AppRole.ADMIN));
        });
```

Here where the Jwt generated (I have seen here StackOverflow this solution)

```
 public async Task<string> GenerateEncodedTokenAsync(string userName, ClaimsIdentity claimsIdentity)
        {
            List<Claim> claims = new List<Claim>()
            {
                 new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, userName),
                 new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, await jwtOptions.JtiGenerator()),
                 new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Iat, ToUnixEpochDate(jwtOptions.IssuedAt).ToString(), ClaimValueTypes.Integer64),
                 claimsIdentity.FindFirst(jwtClaimConfiguration[nameof(JwtClaimOptions.Rol)]),
                 claimsIdentity.FindFirst(jwtClaimConfiguration[nameof(JwtClaimOptions.ApiAccess)])
             };
            var user = await userManager.FindByNameAsync(userName);
            var roles = await userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);

            claims.AddRange(roles.Select(role => new Claim(ClaimsIdentity.DefaultRoleClaimType, role)));

            JwtSecurityToken jwt = new JwtSecurityToken(
                issuer: jwtOptions.Issuer,
                audience: jwtOptions.Audience,
                notBefore: jwtOptions.NotBefore,
                expires: jwtOptions.Expiration,
                signingCredentials: jwtOptions.SigningCredentials,
                claims: claims
            );

            return new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(jwt);
        }
```

The Jwt token contains the role! Here is the payload, as you can see the Role has been added, the user has the "User" role.:

```
{
  "sub": "demo",
  "jti": "a80c4744-6f2d-4e00-8ab2-36614fa3f363",
  "iat": 1557682058,
  "rol": "acc",
  "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role": "User",
  "nbf": 1557682058,
  "exp": 1557689258,
  "iss": "api",
  "aud": "https://localhost:34545/"
}
```

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2019/01/08/aspnet-core-22-role-based-authorization-tutorial-with-example-api) post. I think you are missing the authentication configuration in the startup file i.e. `services.AddAuthentication(...)` and `services.AddJwtBearer(...)` calls. Also, when passing the `Authorization` header, you are missing the `Bearer ` before the Jwt token.

Answer (score 1):

please order middleware in right way

```
 first =>  app.UseRouting();
 second => app.UseAuthentication();
 third=>  app.UseAuthorization();
```